# cpack component install does not work

Tags: cmake, cpack

I want the cpack to take only certain components. But he takes both run and deb components. I looked at a lot of sources.  including this [cpack component level install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663955/cpack-component-level-install) . but I did not understand what I was doing wrong. Tell me please, what did I do wrong?
My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(testProj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testProj ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX .)

install(FILES temp.h DESTINATION someFolder
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE COMPONENT deb
        )

install(FILES Alpha0.400000.txt DESTINATION someFolder
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE COMPONENT run
        )

set(CPACK_TGZ_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_ALL deb)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL deb)

include(CPack)
```

my steps to get an artifact

```
cmake . 
make 
cpack .

CPack: Create package using STGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: testProj
CPack: - Install project: testProj
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/danyal/testProj/test/testProj-0.1.1-Linux.sh generated.
CPack: Create package using TGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: testProj
CPack: - Install project: testProj
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/danyal/testProj/test/testProj-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz generated.
CPack: Create package using TZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: testProj
CPack: - Install project: testProj
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/danyal/testProj/test/testProj-0.1.1-Linux.tar.Z generated.
```

and testProj-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz contains

```
someFolder
   -temp.h
   -Alpha0.400000.txt
```

Comment: Which CPack generator do you use (that is, what kind of package is created - `.tgz`, `.rpm`, etc.)? See [wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Component_Install_With_CPack) about enabling component packaging for specific generator.

Comment: Yes, I tried write in my CMakeLists set(CPACK_TGZ_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON) but it also does not work

Comment: So you use `TGZ` package generator, and it produces single `testProj.tgz` file, which includes both `temp.h` and `Alpha0.400000.txt`. Do I correctly understand what you have now?

Comment: yes, but it generates tar.gz 
`CPack: Create package using TGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: testProj
CPack: - Install project: testProj
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/danyal/testProj/test/testProj-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz generated.`

Comment: Add these messages generated by CPack into the question post (via [edit]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the following to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)
```

I ran into exactly the same problem and had to dive into the source to find the answer. The following function gives the answer:

```
bool cmCPackArchiveGenerator::SupportsComponentInstallation() const
{
  // The Component installation support should only
  // be activated if explicitly requested by the user
  // (for backward compatibility reason)
  return IsOn("CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL");
}
```

For compatibility reasons any archive packaging, i.e. ZIP and TGZ doesn't use component installations.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, I think you should call make on the `package` target created by Cmake and not call cpack directly, i.e. call `make package` instead of `cpack .`.

Alternatively, if you do call cpack directly you can pass the component(s) you want to package as a command line argument. e.g. `cpack -D CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL="deb"` (separated by ';' for multiple components)

(Note the proper variable is `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` not `CPACK_COMPONENT_ALL`)

- [More info on Cpack command line program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cpack.1.html)
- [More info on Cpack Component Packaging](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Component_Install_With_CPack)
- [More info on Cpack Component Variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackComponent.html)
- [More info on General CPack Variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html)